# Direct3D Map Pixels Black

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, direct3d11

Im trying to map pixel data as a byte array to a dynamic texture using direct3d, for some reason the resulting pixel data is black and its not getting transfered.  I have converted this code directly from using updatesubresource before, but now im using map/unmap.

```
ID3D11Texture2D* d3dtex = (ID3D11Texture2D*)textureHandle;
assert(d3dtex);

ID3D11DeviceContext* ctx = NULL;
m_Device->GetImmediateContext(&ctx);
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
ZeroMemory(&mappedResource, sizeof(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE));

//    Disable GPU access to the vertex buffer data.
ctx->Map(d3dtex, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE, 0, &mappedResource);
//    Update the vertex buffer here.
memcpy(mappedResource.pData, dataPtr, textureWidth * textureHeight * 4);
//    Reenable GPU access to the vertex buffer data.
ctx->Unmap(d3dtex, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking the `HRESULT` return from the `ID3D11DeviceContext::Map` function. Likely, the texture cannot be mapped. There are several reasons why a texture in D3D11 might not be mappable, the most obvious is that it was not created with the `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE` access flag (when you are using `D3D11_MAP_WRITE` in the call to `Map`). If you force on the D3D11 debug layer, the debug output will print out a detailed message about the failure.

If you are relying on mapping a Unity internally created texture, you should not assume it is mappable. Using `UpdateSubresource` (as you were using) is more widely compatible, regardless of what flags were used to create the texture. You could query the `CPUAccessFlags` on the texture, using `ID3D11Texture2D::GetDesc`, and decide which update method to use (map/update).